# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, poo

No se porque me da ese **error**, tengo la siguiente funcion que me inserta un usuario(y quiero que si se guarda de forma **exitosa** me retorne el objeto avabado de guardar):

```
public function insertar($usuario){
     if (get_class($usuario) === "Usuario") {
        $this->conexion->conectar();
        if ($this->conexion != null) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais,fecha_registro) 
                VALUES(
                '".$usuario->getNombre()."',
                '".$usuario->getApellidos()."',
                '".$usuario->getEmail()."',
                '".$usuario->getPassword()."',
                '".$usuario->getFechaNacimiento()."',
                '".$usuario->getPais()."',
                '".$usuario->getFechaRegistro()."'
            );";
            $result = $this->conexion->getConnection()->query($sql);


            if ($result) {
                return $usuario;
            } else {
                return null;
            }


        } else {
            echo 'HUBO UN ERROR EN LA CONEXION DESDE  \'INSERTAR USUARIOS\'';
        }

     } else {
        return null;
     }
}
```

Hago las siguientes **pruebas:**

```
 $uh = new UsuarioHandler();
$var = new Usuario(0,"jose","apellidos","ddfg@asdasd.com","passwosdfrd","españa",'1434-04-03','2000-01-01');

echo $result =  $uh->insertar($var);

var_dump($result);
```

Entonces el **problema** esta  en el `return` del if si sale todo **correcto** o sea aqui :

```
if ($result) {
      return $usuario;
}
```

Porque cuando hago el `var_dump($result)` que deberia contener el objeto que acabo de **insertar** en vez de displayearlo lo que me arroja son los siguientes errores :

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string in
```

O sea, lo que interpreto es que al hacer el `return` lo castea a string por defecto y por eso peta o que ?

Comment: No puedes usar `echo` porque estas retornando un objeto.  Simplemente remueve el `echo`.

Comment: exactamente eso era, y ademas con el `var_dump()` he comprobado que devuelve el objeto y lo hace. Perfecto. Mil gracias. Una duda a añadir es que ¿Si no uso echo como puedo displayear un `$objeto` de PHP?

Comment: Con var_dump().

Comment: sin usar `var_dump()` digo

Comment: @josanangel para mostra un objeto, lo normal es que lo recorras con algun bucle o llamando a las propiedades directamente, aun que tambien se podria utilizar el metodo magico `__toString()` para indicar que deberia suceder cuando el objeto es convertido a string (info: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)